# LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUMN)) in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a query to collect all the rows with column `A` not null and not blank.

When I used this:

```
AND A.EXP_GRAD_TERM is not null AND A.EXP_GRAD_TERM <> ' '
```

I got 1169 records which all have some values for the field.

But when I used this:

```
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(A.EXP_GRAD_TERM)) is not null
```

I got 1932 records. They have the rows with values and rows with blanks. I even convert the column, the column only has blanks or the values, not other weird invisible character.

I do not know why. I thought they should have worked the same way.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What would be the result of `AND LTRIM(RTRIM(A.EXP_GRAD_TERM)) is not null AND A.EXP_GRAD_TERM <>' '`

Comment: `763` rows consist of just empty strings or only space characters, these do not count as `NULL`. And BTW trailing spaces are not significant in string comparisons so `<> ' '`  and `<> ''` are the same thing

Answer (score 2):

**LTRIM() function:**

> Returns a character expression after it removes leading blanks.

**RTRIM() function:**

> Returns a character string after truncating all trailing spaces.

They are different from IsNull or empty string condition `(CASE WHEN IS NULL OR <>'')`

**References**

- [LTRIM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ltrim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [RTRIM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You could 'trim' it even further, trailing spaces are ignored in comparisons anyway, so `RTRIM` is also not necessary.

Comment: @honey. Neither is LTRIM here.

Answer (score 2):

This expression:

```
 LTRIM(RTRIM(A.EXP_GRAD_TERM)) is not null
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
A.EXP_GRAD_TERM is not null
```

An empty string is different from `NULL`, so removing spaces -- even from a string that only has spaces -- has no effect on the `NULL` comparison.

If you are confused, perhaps you have experience with Oracle where empty strings and `NULL` are the same thing.  That is a peculiar property of Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Combine `COALESCE()` with `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()`:

```
AND RTRIM(LTRIM(COALESCE(A.EXP_GRAD_TERM, ''))) <> ''
```

`COALESCE(A.EXP_GRAD_TERM, '')` will return `''` for every `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

see if you want to get the values that are not null and not empty you can use isnull (exp, replace_value)

```
AND RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(A.EXP_GRAD_TERM, ''))) <> ''
```

`isnull` isnull replaces a null value for which you want to replace it. you could also use `COALESCE` which *"returns the first non-null expression among your arguments"*

*One apparent advantage that `COALESCE` has over `ISNULL` is that it supports more than two inputs, whereas ISNULL supports only two. Another advantage of COALESCE is that it's a standard function (namely, defined by the ISO/ANSI SQL standards), whereas ISNULL is T-SQL–specific. These differences between the two functions are fairly straightforward.*

if you want more information about the differences between ISNULL and COALESCE you can see it on [this link](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/coalesce-vs-isnull)